# how to get a sum of column in laravel mysql eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to calculate the sum of the `amount`, but getting undefined error.

This is my code:

```
DB::table('fees_category')
            ->select('is_subcategory', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_fees'))->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)
            ->where('is_subcategory' , $category_id)
            ->whereIn('id',$cate_sub)
            ->groupBy('is_subcategory')
            ->get();
```

Comment: remove one ) in your DB::raw

Comment: Valid version is:

    \DB::table('fees_category')
        ->select('is_subcategory', \DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_fees'))
        ->where('school_id', '=', \Auth::user()->school_id)
        ->where('is_subcategory', '=', $category_id)
        ->whereIn('id', $cate_sub)
        ->groupBy('is_subcategory')
        ->get();

Doesnt works? Can you paste error message?

Comment: undefined only coming...

Comment: i am getting the value through json, so return value is undefined

Comment: Could you show more code? I doubt the result of this query id 'undefined'

Comment: $amount_fees    = $users->total_fees;
  
  
  echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success' ,'fees_cat'=>$amount_fees));

Comment: $users = DB::table('fees_category')
                ->select('is_subcategory', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_fees'))
    ->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)
    ->where('is_subcategory' , $category_id)
    ->whereIn('id',$cate_sub)
                ->groupBy('is_subcategory')
                ->get();